# Uncommon Ruby syntax <<ABC – what does it accomplish?

Tags: ruby

Just found this piece of code in a Google Ruby API client on Github.

```
NOT_FOUND_ERROR = <<END
Could not load the default credentials. Browse to
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
for more information
END
```

I never saw it and tested it in the console:

```
>> NOT_FOUND_ERROR = <<END
blabla
END
=> "blabla\n"
```

So basically it is a weird way to create a string? What's the motivation for using this syntax rather than `NOT_FOUND_ERROR = "blabla\n"` ?

EDIT: As this question was marked with "possible duplicate" I want to explain why it is not just a dup. The question that is a possible duplicate simply asks what a certain ruby script does. This Ruby script also includes the `<<ABC` syntax and this obviously is the core of the question, but it is not really helpful because it is hard to find. Besides that, I am going further and ask for the motivation to use this notation over creating a normal string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is HEREDOC. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)(wiki) and [here](http://makandracards.com/makandra/1675-using-heredoc-for-prettier-ruby-code)(Ruby instances). Usually heredocs used for more readability of multiline text.

Comment: You can also use single quotes, double quotes, %q, and %Q for multiline strings.