# What does <<CONSTANT do?

Tags: ruby, push, constants, service-object

Reading an article and saw the following notation. Can anyone help me interpret? I've only seen << used to push elements inside of an array, and my use of constants has been limited.

```
def template(title, date)
  <<TEMPLATE
end
```

For further context, the full article is [here](http://blog.arkency.com/2015/03/extract-a-service-object-in-any-framework/).

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865329/uncommon-ruby-syntax-abc-what-does-it-accomplish?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: This question has a good title.  The exemplar does not, so I'm going to steal this title and edit it into the exemplar.  Thanks!

Comment: glad i could be of help. thanks for making the connection